# Add values to object in JS when using groupBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I am using `mapValues` and `groupBy` to group and create `keys` when two items have the same `typeId`.

For example the original data is

```
{
    "Name": "One",
    "typeId": 1
},
{
    "Name": "Two",
    "typeId": 2
},
{
    "Name": "One Two",
    "typeId": 1
},
{
    "Name": "Three",
    "typeId": 3
},
{
    "Name": "Three Two",
    "typeId": 3
}
```

and by using `groupBy` I group the objects with the matching `typeId` and `omit` the `typeId` value from the `objects as...

```
const GroupedTypes = Object.entries(
   _.mapValues(_.groupBy(data, 'typeID'), rlist =>
      rlist.map(type => _.omit(type, 'typeID'))
   )
);
```

Returning as intended...

```
[
    "1",
    [
      {
        "Name": "One",
      },
      {
        "Name": "One Two",
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    "2",
    [
      {
        "Name": "Two",
      }
    ]
  ],
  [
    "3",
    [
      {
        "Name": "Three",
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Name": "Three Two",
      }
    ]
]
```

However, I would also like to add an object for `Name` from the value `Name` in the first `0` object. Thus ending up with something like..

```
[
    "1",
    "One",
    [
      {
        "Name": "One",
      },
      {
        "Name": "One Two",
      }
    ]
],
[
    "2",
    "Two",
    [
      {
        "Name": "Two",
      }
    ]
],
[
    "3",
    "Three",
    [
      {
        "Name": "Three",
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "Name": "Three Two",
      }
    ]
]
```

I've been looking through the `lodash` documentation and cannot find a method that works. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is lodash necessary? This is trivial to accomplish with built-in Javascript methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `map` with `splice`.

```js
const FilterGuests = [{
  "Name": "One",
  "typeId": 1
}, {
  "Name": "Two",
  "typeId": 2
}, {
  "Name": "One Two",
  "typeId": 1
}, {
  "Name": "Three",
  "typeId": 3
}, {
  "Name": "Three Two",
  "typeId": 3
}];

const GroupedTypes = Object.entries(
  _.mapValues(_.groupBy(FilterGuests, 'typeId'), rlist =>
    rlist.map(roomType => _.omit(roomType, 'typeId'))
  )
).map(e => {
  e.splice(1, 0, e[1][0].Name);
  return e;
});

console.log(GroupedTypes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to group the items based on `typeId`:

```js
const input=[{"Name":"One","typeId":1},{"Name":"Two","typeId":2},{"Name":"One Two","typeId":1},{"Name":"Three","typeId":3},{"Name":"Three Two","typeId":3}]

const merged = input.reduce((acc, { Name, typeId }) => {
  acc[typeId] = acc[typeId] || [ typeId, Name, []];
  acc[typeId][2].push({ Name });
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(merged))
```

You need to create an accumulator object with each `typeId` as key and the array you need in the output as its value. If the key is not already present, add the key with `[ typeId, Name, []]` as value. This way, the first item's `Name` will be in the output. This is how the accumulator/`merged` will look like:

```
{
      "1": [1, "One", [{ "Name": "One" }, { "Name": "One Two" }]],
      "2": [2, "Two", [{ "Name": "Two" }]],
      "3": [3, "Three", [{ "Name": "Three" }, { "Name": "Three Two" }]]
}
```

Then use, [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get just the values of this object as an array

Comment: Thank you Adiga. The other answered my question regarding `groupBy`, however as stated above this may be the better method of achieving the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.map()` and not `_.mapValues()`, which works on objects as well, and returns an array. In the map's callback, get the group key from the 2nd param, take the 1st elements `Name`, and return an array in the requested format:

```js
const FilterGuests = [{"Name":"One","typeId":1},{"Name":"Two","typeId":2},{"Name":"One Two","typeId":1},{"Name":"Three","typeId":3},{"Name":"Three Two","typeId":3}];

const GroupedTypes = _.map(
  _.groupBy(FilterGuests, 'typeId'), 
  (rlist, key) =>
  [
    key, 
    _.get(rlist, '[0].Name'), 
    rlist.map(roomType => _.omit(roomType, 'typeId'))
  ]
)

console.log(GroupedTypes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```